# Why convoloution neural net have to find filter values ?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

I'm new to ML stuff and one of the thing that I don't understand about CNN, is that why CNN have to find the values of filter at convolution layer, why don' they use existing filters and only find the weights for neural network after fully connected layer.

Comment: What are these "existing filters" and where do they come from?

Comment: Because the success of CNN's is precisely the adaptive convolution Al filters. Prior to this the state of art was SVM (ie instead of fully connected Nn) taking Sift filter inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of CNNs are that they **learn** the filters that are the best for the task at hand. By using *existing* filters, we wouldn't be able to achieve such high performance.

CNNs are built so that each layer's filters are applied to the features extracted from the previous layer. This way the features extracted from CNNs are **hierarchical**.

Imagine a CNN used for facial recognition. Typically the first few layers are formed to extract basic shapes (lines, curves, etc.), layers near the middle extract more abstract facial features (eyes, noses, etc.), while the final layers would extract face-like features.

[image]

This way the filters of each CNN are tailored to extract the **best** features for each task. By using generic *existing* image filters, we wouldn't be able to get this result.